# What kind model or brand guitar do I have what kind is this

Tags: guitar

I have an Acoustic 6 string that has plastic tuning keys on it also the top of the neck goes into a point by the keys, not flat.

The tag on the inside states the name Austin and after that Lonestar in the middle. It says Houston Texas bottom left-hand Corner, the tag also states on the right-hand bottom corner "made in Mexico".

Tell me about this guitar, why can I not find it on the internet, what kind of guitar is this?

Comment: Sorry but you have made this very confusing by not structuring your post in sentences.  A bit of punctuation would make a huge difference here.

Answer (score 1):

The Lonestar line of Guitars and Mandolins were not made for very many years. They were distributed by LPD Music, a wholesale music company.  I believe they were manufactured in Paracho Mexico. The mandolins had deep bodies and solid cedar tops. I never sold the guitars, so I can't tell you much about them, but they were likely solid cedar also.

You won't find them on the internet because the brand didn't last very long.

If I can find an old LPD catalogue I'll update with the product description.

EDIT: Here's link to the Internet Archive of the Product site:

http://web.archive.org/web/20030201114253/http://www.lonestarguitars.com/